# dc.js Threshold/Color Band For Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, bar-chart, dc.js

I'm trying to get bar charts in dc.js to have threshold coloring/color bands in the background. As an example, on a chart with x axis values from 0 to 100, the background behind values 0-50 would be white, 51-75 would be yellow, and 76-100 would be red. As far as I can tell, there isn't any built in functionality for this in dc, so I've thought of three workarounds:

1. Manually change the chart's svg
2. Create another bar chart that acts as the background and compose the two charts
3. Create an area chart that acts as the background and compose the two charts

None of these seem like a particularly ideal solution, so I was wondering if there was another way that I'm missing. If not, which of these would probably work best/be the simplest with an elastic x axis?

Comment: I'm reading this again and I realize you might be referring to a row chart (rather than a bar chart) and you might be looking for the chart background (not the row/bar background) to be colored.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm using a bar chart (vertical), not a row chart, and I'm looking for the background to be different colors instead of the bars themselves. Pretty much what the colorAccessor does, except on the background instead of the bars.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I don't have a good solution for you that would work with an elastic x-axis.   I removed my answer so that others will see this question as unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just manually adding colored rectangles to the svg using d3 selections and chart.chartBodyG() combined with some math. For updating with the elastic x axis, I just removed all of the previously drawn rectangles and then re-drew them. Not particularly pretty during the transition, but it works.